# How to choose intial values for lmfit least square?

Tags: python, non-linear-regression, lmfit

I have following function:

```
def function(self, params, x):
        a = params["a"]
        b = params["b"]
        c = params["c"]

        return a * np.exp(-x/b) + c
```

My current residual is:

```
def residual(self, params, x, y):
        return (y - self.function(params, x))**2
```

Parameters:

```
a = needs to be negative
b = needs to be positive
c = any value
```

I am using lmfit and least square method. This problem should be solved by using non linear regression.
My questions are:

1.) How can I find out whether the fit is ok? lmfit provides "message" but it says success eventhough SSE is extremely high (and parameters a, b, c as well.). I read that reduced chi-square could be used as indication. Is it true? Can I suppose that if reduced-chi square is <= 1 fit should be ok?

2.) Second and main problem is how to guess initial values. Right now my starting values are -1, 1, 1 and sometimes it finds solid solution but sometimes SSE and parameters are huge (to e18 for example) so it is obviously not ok. The same problem was solved when I put some different starting values but I was only trying some random values... So is there some way how to generate some solid starting values so my app does not show the user bad graph with huge SSE and a, b, c? And it seems the solution is extremely dependant on the provided initial values.

Input vary all the time. Basically any float number (for money). Examples:

```
profitList = [-10000, 100, 1000, 10000]
utilityList = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1]
```

or

```
pL = [10, 500, 820, 1000, 10000]
ul = [0, 0,1, 0,4, 0,7, 1]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is always (really) advisable to include a minimal, complete example of code that shows what you are doing.  Your code for your model function and residual as `x`, `y`, `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Are we supposed to assume that `pL` and/or `utilityList` corresponds to one of `x` or `y`?  Because, no we will not assume that.  You have to say what you are doing.  You have to say that with actual, working code.

> 1.) How can I find out whether the fit is ok? lmfit provides "message" but it says success eventhough SSE is extremely high (and parameters a, b, c as well.). I read that reduced chi-square could be used as indication. Is it true? Can I suppose that if reduced-chi square is <= 1 fit should be ok?

Plot the resulting data and model. All of the statistics related to chi-square rely on an understanding of the uncertainties. If you are not indicating that you have that, then you probably do not have that.

It is hard to beat a visual inspection of the data with the model.

> 2.) Second and main problem is how to guess initial values. Right now my starting values are -1, 1, 1 and sometimes it finds solid solution but sometimes SSE and parameters are huge (to e18 for example) so it is obviously not ok. The same problem was solved when I put some different starting values but I was only trying some random values... So is there some way how to generate some solid starting values so my app does not show the user bad graph with huge SSE and a, b, c? And it seems the solution is extremely dependant on the provided initial values.

Perhaps unsurprisingly, the answer is the same as for your first question: Plot the data with the model and your initial parameter values.

For sure, fitting is a *refinement* process and you need to start with reasonable starting values.  If you truly have no idea with the values could or ought to be, then you probably do not understand your data or your model very well.  If that is the case, you will have to spend some learning what reasonable parameter ranges are.

As a side note, if you are trying to model data that changes exponentially over more than one or two orders of magnitude, you almost certainly will be better off fitting the logarithm of the data to the logarithm of your exponential model.

Also, why is your residual taking the square of "data - model"?  Is the intention to hamper the solving algorithm to not see the sign of the residual?  That will be the effect.   You almost certainly will be better off not doing that.